# Get hidden input value inside a for loop to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, loops, for-loop

I have this code on php

```
for ($i=0;$i<$myCounter;$i++) {
    $inum++; //showing only by the counter.
    echo "<hr>ID de Producto ".$inum.":".$dataReceive[$i]["Detalle"]["IDENDODET"];
    echo '
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="IDENDODET" id="IDENDODET" class="IDENDODET" value="'.$dataReceive[$i]["Detalle"]["IDENDODET"].'">
            <button type="button" id="Delete" name="Delete" style="border:0;background-color:yellow;" onclick="deletecookieTest()"/>Borrar este ID</button>
        </form>';
}
```

And I want the value from the IDENDODET to be sent with the button clicked. I've tried this:

```
 var form = document.querySelector('input[name=IDENDODET]').value;
```

but that only gives me the first value when the button is clicked instead of the value of the form in particular. For example no matter which button I click below I get "165" instead of "167" which I need to later delete that section.
[here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH5UH.png)

Comment: When you say first value which value are you talking about? I only see one value in the form. Have you done a view source to see if the value is being properly populated?

Comment: I added a picture to help out. It always shows the first value with the selector. With querySelectorAll it shows me all of the values. But I need to get the value in particular to later be able to delete the API product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another issue that you have in the code. You technically can't have the button have the same id, but what I would do is have the id being passed into the deleteCookieTest function. This way you don't have to traverse the DOM.

```
<button type="button" name="Delete" style="border:0;background-color:yellow;" onclick="deletecookieTest('.$dataReceive[$i]["Detalle"]["IDENDODET"].')"/>
Borrar este ID
</button>
```

Comment: Is there a way to send two variables (IDENDODET + Quantity) instead of just one (IDENDODET) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which will give all the elements. This will give a static nodelist and then use `forEach` to get the value from each item

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name=IDENDODET]').forEach(function(elem){
  console.log(elem.value);

})
```

Comment: this works, it shows me all values. but I need to send the particular value that's chosen to a post